# Cannot find definition of 'ib_lock_t' in mysql server source code

Tags: c++, mysql, c, declaration, definition

I read source code here: [link of mysql source code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/a2757a60a7527407d08115e44e889a25f22c96c6/storage/innobase/include/lock0types.h)

But after I searched the whole repository, I cannot find the defination of `ib_lock_t`.

search link: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ib_lock_t

search result:

[image]

**Where is it defined?**

Answer (score 0):

**Found:** https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/a2757a60a7527407d08115e44e889a25f22c96c6/storage/innobase/include/lock0priv.h

**Line: 110**

I am still confused with the preprocess:

`#define lock_t ib_lock_t`.

Why to replace `lock_t`

without no definition of `ib_lock_t`?

Answer (score -2):

I guess it's `struct lock_t` in lock0priv.h file.